# How can I use IBM Watson in my existing ASP.net application

Tags: ibm-cloud, artificial-intelligence, watson

I have an existing ERP in asp.net application, and now I want to integrate IBM watson api in this ERP. How can I do it ? please give an example and put source code also.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  This question does not meet stackoverflow's criteria and will probably get closed.  See here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, you don't specify what Service you what to use.

In this case, Simon O'doherty show you the .[NET SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk) for use all Services from Watson Developer Cloud.

You can see inside the folder [Examples](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk/tree/development/examples) within this SDK, how to call all these services:

- Speech to Text: Voice recognition to Text, converts audio voice into written text.
- Conversation: Allows you to quickly build, test and deploy a bot or virtual agent across mobile devices, messaging platforms like Slack or even on a physical robot.
- Text to Speech: Capabilities to convert written text to natural-sounding speech.
- Language Translator: Translates text from one language to another. The service offers multiple domain-specific models that you can customize based on your unique terminology and language.
- Personality Insights: Extracts personality characteristics based on how a person writes.
- Tone Analyzer: This service uses linguistic analysis to detect communication tones in written text.
- Visual Recognition: Understands the contents of images - visual concepts tag the image, recognize food, find human faces, approximate age and gender, and find similar images in a collection. You can also train the service by creating your own custom concepts.

Example for you know how to call this services (RESTFul API Conversation Service):

```
//import libraries
using IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.Conversation.v1;
using IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.Conversation.v1.Model;
using System;

namespace IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.Conversation.Example
{
    public class ConversationServiceExample
    {
        private ConversationService _conversation = new ConversationService();
        private string _workspaceID;
        private string _inputString = "Turn on the winshield wipers";

        //Every service have username and password or other unique ID
        public ConversationServiceExample(string username, string password, string workspaceID)
        {
            _conversation.SetCredential(username, password);
            _workspaceID = workspaceID;

            Message();
        }

        #region Message
        private void Message()
        {
            MessageRequest messageRequest = new MessageRequest()
            {
                Input = new { Text = _inputString }
            };
```